# ruby loaderror inotify

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am working from a Linux machine - I get the following error from irb when I type require 'inotify'.

Appreciate any help/pointers.

> irb(main):001:0> require 'inotify'
>       LoadError: no such file to load -- inotify
>         from :29:in `require'
>         from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
>         from (irb):1
>         from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `'

```
    irb(main):002:0> Gem.path
=> ["/home/johnq/.gem/ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1"]
irb(main):003:0> 
johnq$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.1.1, 3.0.9)
actionpack (3.1.1, 3.0.9)
activemodel (3.1.1, 3.0.9)
activerecord (3.1.1, 3.0.9)
activeresource (3.1.1, 3.0.9)
activesupport (3.1.1, 3.0.9)
arel (2.2.1, 2.0.10)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.21, 1.0.15)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
daemons (1.1.4)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
ffi (1.0.10)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.5.0)
json (1.6.1)
mail (2.3.0, 2.2.19)
mime-types (1.17.2, 1.16)
minitest (2.7.0, 1.6.0)
multi_json (1.0.3)
mysql (2.8.1)
polyglot (0.3.2, 0.3.1)
rack (1.3.5, 1.2.3)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3, 0.6.14)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1, 0.5.7)
rails (3.1.1, 3.0.9)
railties (3.1.1, 3.0.9)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
rb-inotify (0.8.8)
rdoc (3.11, 3.6.1, 2.5.8)
sprockets (2.0.3)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10, 1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.30, 0.3.28)
johnq$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rb-inotify'
=> true

johnq$ gem remove rb-inotify
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command remove
johnq$ man gem
No manual entry for gem

johnq$ sudo gem uninstall rb-inotify
Password: 
Successfully uninstalled rb-inotify-0.8.8
johnq$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'inotify'
LoadError: no such file to load -- inotify
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> 
johnq$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/johnq/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. When you have the gem, `require 'rb-inotify'`is working in your session. Then, you uninstall the gem *and* use the wrong `require` statement. Of course, this doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: I am working on a legacy program which uses require 'inotify'. I tried gem install inotify but i could not find any such gem. I found rb-inotify but things are different in its syntax and the program gives errors. I am new to ruby and no expert on gems. Can you point me to the site or version which provides the inotify gem (and not rb-inotify). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several gem front-ends for Linux inotify. See [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=inotify). You'll have to find out which one your code relies on.

[ruby-inotify](https://github.com/aredridel/ruby-inotify) seems to be a good candidate.