# Ruby Gems with Gitlab no such file to load -- rb-inotify

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gitolite, gitlab

I am using Gitlab and I am trying to follow these instructions to upgrade my gitolite v2 to v3:

"If this issue occurs in 2.9.x you should reinstall gitolite.

1) backup all repositories. Just copy /home/git/repositories/* elsewhere.

2) Install new gitolite. See https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/installation.md

3) copy repositories back.

4) sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake gitlab:gitolite:update_keys && sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake gitlab:gitolite:update_repos

That's all.

That steps also related to users who wants to update gitolite v2 to v3"

My Gemfile and Gemfile.lock have rb-inotify in them as shown below:

```
gitlabhq@build:~/gitlabhq$ grep notify Gemfile
gem 'rb-inotify', :require => linux_only('rb-inotify')
gitlabhq@build:~/gitlabhq$ grep notify Gemfile.lock
rb-inotify (0.8.8)
rb-inotify
```

I am trying to update my keys and repos using the following commands but I always get the error "**no such file to load --rb-inotify**"

```
gitlabhq@geminibuild:~/gitlabhq$ sudo -u gitlabhq -H bundle exec rake gitlab:gitolite:update_keys
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- rb-inotify
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've tried to do a bundle install , and the list of 'Using " does not contain the rb-notify gem.

I've tried to install the rb-inotify gem like so:

```
sudo -u gitlabhq gem install rb-inotify
```

I've wiped the Gemfile.lock file and then run:

```
sudo -u gitlabhq bundle install
```

Still no luck.

How can I get Gitlab to recognize and use rb-inotify. Thank you -

Comment: Did you try to install `ruby-inotify`? https://github.com/aredridel/ruby-inotify (as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061881/ruby-loaderror-inotify)

Comment: Yes I cloned that repository and ran 'sudo gem install ruby-inotify' and received a success message but still get the same error with the 'sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake gitlab:gitolite:update_keys' command

Comment: Can you try and remove any '`inotify`' reference `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`, to see if you can execute the `rake` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seemed to have fixed it by running:

```
bundle install --without production
bundle install
```

Comment: FYI: The inotify gem is marked as development dependency therefore this works. A side effect is a lot of unused garbage. Alternatively you can add `gem "rb-inotify"` to the bottom of the Gemfile and run `bundle install` again (you have to do this on each update though until it is fixed)

Answer (score 19):

Recognizing that this is a bit old, I thought I'd leave something for posterity. In order to make these calls work you simply need to append:

`RAILS_ENV=production`

to your command. This is listed in the [trouble shooting guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide) under the "Gitlab" section.