# Gitlab project - failed to run "rails generate"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gitlab

Introduction:

- I have an installation of gitlab on a local lxc container running ubuntu 13.10 - saucy.
- I have installed RVM as a as a multi-user installation - in `/usr/local/rvm`
- In order to run gitlab with RVM I have created a wrapper for the bundle command as specified [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Installing-Gitlab-with-RVM)
- The gitlab application is running correctly but I have a problem running `rails generate` function

The steps I followed :

- `$ sudo su git` - to login as the git user
- `$ cd /home/git/gitlab`
- `$ source /etc/profile/`
- `$ rvm use gemset ruby-2.1.1@gitlab` - a custom gemset I created
- `$ gem list` - lists all the gems that appear in the Gemfile for gitlab, so I know I am on the right gemset
- `$ rails -v` -> Rails 4.0.3
- `$ rails generate --help` will output

  ```
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require': cannot load such file -- rb-inotify (LoadError)
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
  from /home/git/gitlab/config/application.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `require'
  from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:8:in `require'
  from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
  ```

What I gathered from this output is that it is in some way trying to use the `ruby-2.1.1@global` gemset.

If I switch to that gemset `$ rvm use gemset ruby-2.1.1@global`, `$ gem list` will output

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.4)
bundler (1.5.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.3)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (2.1.1.0)
```

And if I run bundle install or the wrapper bundle install it says that all the gems are installed.

What am I missing here?

--------------------edit------------------

found a way to make it work

I followed the [trouble shooting guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide) and tried 
`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails generate --help` and it worked

Apparently as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032580/ruby-gems-with-gitlab-no-such-file-to-load-rb-inotify) in the last comment, `rb-inotify` is "marked as development dependency" therefore forcing the environment to be production, it won't try to use it

Answer (score 0):

To resolve
`'require': cannot load such file -- rb-inotify`

You need to install `rb-inotify` gem. Use the below command to install it:

```
gem install rb-inotify
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately it didn't help.
I still get the same error and the gem rb-inotify is installed on the gemset

Comment: Do you see it when you do `gem list`?

Comment: Yes : rb-inotify (0.9.3)

Comment: Make sure you have it in your custom gemset `ruby-2.1.1@gitlab`

Comment: it is there
git@gitlab:~/gitlab$ rvm current gemset

ruby-2.1.1@gitlab

git@gitlab:~/gitlab$ gem list


*** LOCAL GEMS ***
...
rb-inotify (0.9.3)
...

Comment: Thats strange. Do you get the exact same error `'require': cannot load such file -- rb-inotify ` or the error changed?

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in Gemfile

```
gem 'rb-inotify'
```

and give `bundle install` then
please give `gem list` in terminal.

if it is there means to fix this problem require this gem in `application.rb` like,

```
require "rb-inotify"
```

this problem will solve.

Comment: I added `require` "rb-inotify" in application.rb and now it gives a different error 

    /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- rb-inotify (LoadError)

Comment: sure you are having `rb-inotify` gem in your gemset means your gemset not loading properly.instead of `rvm` please try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708916/use-rvmrc-or-ruby-version-file-to-set-a-project-gemset-with-rvm#answers